# Why was a topic to understand the SEO strategies of a particular website closed as 'off topic?'

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I wrote the question here:

[How does Indeed.com make it to the top of every single search for every single city I search for?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/42730/how-does-indeed-com-make-it-to-the-top-of-every-single-search-for-every-single-c#comment41282_42730)

I posted this question to the community so as to learn more about SEO and page ranking strategies through the effectiveness of another company's efforts.

This was closed as "off topic" why?

I strongly disagree that this is off topic, especially on 'webmasters' where the tags are about seo, search engings, serps, and other factors to rank well in search engine results.

Understanding the effectiveness and methods of one's success helps anyone who is interested evaluate their own methodoligies and thus become more educated and more experienced about what it is they are trying to accomplish.

Please reopen the question.

Answer (score 0):

From the FAQ:

> What kind of questions can I ask here?
>   If your question generally covers the operation of websites **which you control** […]
>   […]
>   What kind of questions should I not ask here?
>   You should only ask practical, **answerable** questions based on **actual problems that you face**.

You, on the other hand, were asking people to speculate about the business model/practices of a site you don't control, regarding a situation that isn't even all that true, cf. first comment, cf. Google Personalized Search, to do something that most here probably consider a bit sketchy in the first place.

There's no real answer, it wouldn't really help you, and it's not your site. 
I personally would've put it under "not constructive."

[Sidenote: The "indeed.com url structure" query is now topped off(for me) by your semi-repost over at StackOverflow on the same topic.]

Comment: Ok, granted I did not read the FAQ to understand I had to own the site. Fine. THen which stackexchange site is this question most suited for?

Comment: .. but, you are completely wrong on 'there is no real answer' and 'this wouldn't really help you.' I could think of several specific answers that are direct and viable, and that I could have easily checked as the correct answer. Also, learning about more effective seo strategies to implement in my own site would definitely help me. Just because you disagree or you personally cannot see the value in the question does not mean it's wrong. Obviously, the rest of the community liked the question given how popular it was becoming. Many people wanted to know the same thing I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you own indeed.com this doesn't meet the requirements set forth in the [faq]:

> If your question generally covers the operation of websites which you control, then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

and

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face